# es posible alinear elementos con float en su base?

Tags: html5, css3

tengo unos div que tienen diferentes alturas y no se como alinearlos por su base en lugar de en su parte superior usando la propiedad FLOAT.

Paso ejemplo de lo que tengo

```css
#marcas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#marcas #contMarcas {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
#marcas figure#der {
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
#marcas figure#izq {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="marcas">
  <div id="contMarcas">
    <figure id="der"> </figure>
    <figure id="izq"> </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

La idea es que quede ambos rectangulos alineados abajo manteniendo float. Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "manteniendo el float"? ¿Qué comportamiento es el que quieres para mantener el uso de esa propiedad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `flex-box` he construido un ejemplo que aparentemente se comporta como el tuyo, nada más que con la especificación que necesitas. (ambos `figure` alineados por la base).

El uso de `float` irremediablemente se acerca a su obsolescencia, actualmente se usan otros `display` que nos otorgan lo que nos daba `float` y muchas cosas más. (vease `display: flex` o `display: grid`).

```css
#marcas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

#marcas #contMarcas {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#marcas figure#der {
    width: 30%;
    height: 90%;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    order: 2;
}

#marcas figure#izq {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="marcas">
  <div id="contMarcas">
    <figure id="der"> </figure>
    <figure id="izq"> </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: perfecto! me voy a meter de lleno con flexbox y la grid de css porque ultimamente estan solucionando todos mis problemas... Muchas gracias por el aporte

Comment: ¡Estupendo! Como siempre digo: el mejor agradecimiento es el voto positivo y la manera de indicar que te ha valido la solución es el marcar la respuesta como aceptada ^^. Y ya verás que gozo cuando vayas aprendiendo a usar estos maravillosos `display`.